# Solve this $\;2\sqrt[4]{\frac{x^4}{3} + 4} = 1 + \sqrt {\frac{3}{2}} |y| \ldots$

Tags: calculus

Solve
$\begin{cases}
2\sqrt[4]{\frac{x^4}{3} + 4} = 1 + \sqrt {\frac{3}{2}} |y|\\[8pt]
2\sqrt[4]{\frac{y^4}{3} + 4} = 1 + \sqrt {\frac{3}{2}} |x|
\end{cases}$

Comment: Wouldn't it just be easier to write the second equation as $x=y$?

Answer (score 2):

Following Ron Gordon's suggestion, and noting that the if $(x,y)$ is a solution, then $(\pm x, \pm y)$ are all solutions, we need to solve:

$$2\sqrt[4]{\frac{x^4}{3}+4}=1+\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}x$$

Both sides to the fourth power:

$$\frac{16x^4}{3}+64=1+2\sqrt6x+9x^2+3\sqrt6x^3+\frac{9x^4}{4}\\$$

It turns out that this expression factors:

$$(x-\sqrt6)^2(37x^2+38\sqrt6x+126)=0$$

So that $x=\sqrt6$.  The quadratic has no real roots.

Answers are then $(\pm\sqrt6,\pm\sqrt6)$.

Comment: Nice work (+1).

Comment: case |x|>|y| và |x|<|y| ....???

Comment: there is impossible to have |x|>|y|.you can prove it. let x=y+a, all >0, then replace x, you can check two equations and have a confirm answer.